# Exception when using wrapper object

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am having trouble getting the following working.

I have a "working" Spring Boot Application which uses Thymeleaf and Spring MVC. When I am trying to send a request back to the server it throws the following error:

```
Internal Server Error 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default value must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setDefaultValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:873)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getNestedPropertyAccessor(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:842)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyAccessorForPropertyPath(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:816)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyAccessorForPropertyPath(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:817)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyHandler(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:724)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.isWritableProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:562)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.checkFieldMarkers(WebDataBinder.java:242)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:157)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:160)
```

I have already tried to debug it, hours, but I am can't figure out what I am missing. Using the structure below, it does not work, using a List without the *Field Wrapper Class* (also see below) e.g. `private List<DTO> dtoList = new ArrayList<>();` it works. I describe some of my attempts at the end.

**My structure:**

the template table row using the fragment:

```
<tr th:each="pac,i : *{dtoList}">
    <div th:include="details/frag :: table_check('dtoList', 'approval', true)"></div>
</tr>
```

the thymeleaf fragment *frag.html*:

```
<th:block th:fragment="table_check (list, field, wrapped)">
    <td>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input th:field="*{__${list}__[__${i.index}__]__${wrapped ? '.currentValue':''}__.__${field}__}"
                   type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" th:id="|${list}_${field}_${i.index}|">
            <th:block th:if="${wrapped}">
                <input th:field="*{__${list}__[__${i.index}__].originalValue.__${field}__}" type="hidden">
            </th:block>
            <label class="custom-control-label" th:for="|${list}_${field}_${i.index}|"></label>
        </div>
    </td>
</th:block>
```

The *SpecialField* Class

```
public class SpecialField extends BasicField<DTO> {
    public SpecialField() {
    }

    public SpecialField(DTO value, boolean changeable) {
        super(value, changeable);
    }

    public SpecialField(DTO value) {
        super(value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasChanged() {
        //some code to check this
        return false;
    }
}
```

The *BasicField* Class

```
public abstract class BasicField<T> implements Field<T> {
    protected boolean changeable = false;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = YYYY_MM_DD)
    protected T originalValue;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = YYYY_MM_DD)
    protected T currentValue;

    public BasicField() {
    }

    protected BasicField(T value, boolean changeable) {
        this.originalValue = value;
        this.currentValue = value;
        this.changeable = changeable;
    }

    protected BasicField(T value) {
        this.originalValue = value;
        this.currentValue = value;
    }

    // getter and setter though one is special

    public void setCurrentValue(T value) {
        if (isChangeable()) {
            currentValue = value;
        }
    }
    public boolean isChangeable() {
        return changeable;
    }
}
```

The *DTO* Class

```
public class DTO extends AbstractDto {
   private boolean approval;
   // getter and setter
}
```

The Class containing the dtoList

```
@Validated
public class BaseDTO extends AbstractDTO {
    private List<SpecialField> dtoList = new ArrayList<>();
    // getter and setter
}
```

My Controller Class (actually, I won't come to this point)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/details", params = { "update" })
    public ModelAndView update(final @Valid @ModelAttribute(name = "baseDto") BaseDto baseDto,
            final BindingResult bindingResult, WebRequest request, final Model model) {
//do smth
}
```

**Attempts to fix:**

- I tried to set the @Value Annotation with a default value, but could not figure out how I can set a default object.
- I tried a generic approach (ListField T being the BaseDto instead of SpecialField), but got an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because my List was initialized as an empty ArrayList without at least one entry.
- I tried to remove the fragment template, but still got the error

I guess it is something very trivial, but I am at a loss here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to deal with it. I replaced the default BasicField Constructor

```
public BasicField() {}
```

with

```
public BasicField(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    this.supplier = supplier;
    this.originalValue = supplier.get();
    this.currentValue = supplier.get();
}
```

and adjusted the SpecialField Constructor accordingly

```
public SpecialField() {
    super(DTO::new);
}
```

therefore originalValue and currentValue can have new instances if I need to have them, and nothing if not. There is surely a better solution to this, but its a way.